# Split up text and process in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a program that generates lots (terabytes) of output and sends it to stdout.

I want to split that output and process it in parallel with a bunch of instances of another program. It can be distributed in any way, as long as the lines are left intact.

Parallel can do this, but it takes a fixed number of lines and restartes the filter process after this:

```
./relgen | parallel -l 100000 -j 32 --spreadstdin ./filter
```

Is there a way to keep a constant number of processes running and distribute data among them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-l` is no good for performance. Use `--block` instead if possible.

You can have the data distributed roundrobin with: `--roundrobin`.

```
./relgen | parallel --block 3M --round-robin -j 32 --pipe ./filter
```

Comment: Using this command the filter-processes are spawned, but only one is running at a time. The others are waiting for input.

Comment: Then relgen generates too slowly: Lower 3M to 0.3M

Comment: relgen is generating fast enough to keep all 32 filter instances running. Still the same behavior with 0.3M.

Comment: Does this run 32 active 'wc's? seq 1000000000| parallel -j32 --pipe --round-robin wc

Comment: It spawns 32 wc's but only one of them is running at a time.

Comment: Upgrade it newest release. If you are running newest release: File a bug report as per: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm now.